# Delete image from Amazon S3 Storage

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete an image from Amazon S3 Storage, but it doesn't delete.

I am using following code:

```
var s3 = AWS.S3(awsCredentials);
s3.deleteObject({
  Bucket: MY_BUCKET,
  Key: myKey
},function (err,data){})
```

but images that I want to delete still persist.

I even used `s3.deleteObjects` function,it returns deleted object names, but when I checked the storage, the images were still there.

Comment: Had you enabled versioning on the S3

Comment: versionId = null on all my images, so it means versioning is not enabled right?

Comment: and after deleteing it does not add any delete marker to the version, it is still null

Comment: is that image in a sub folder on the bucket? Can you paste the path for the image that you are suing?

Comment: yes,  it is in the sub folder.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to use the key in this way and not just the name of the file that is to be deleted then it will work.

```
var s3 = AWS.S3(awsCredentials);
s3.deleteObject({
  Bucket: MY_BUCKET,
  Key: 'some/subfolders/nameofthefile1.extension'
},function (err,data){})
```

Comment: actually I was using for the key following format '/some/subfolders/nameofthefile1.extension' but leading '/' was unnecessary.

Comment: Not just unnecessary, but incorrect.   The S3 convention is that the root of the bucket is an empty string, not a `/`.  The follow-up question is why you didn't encounter an exception when trying to delete a non-existent object.  The answer, best contemplated when you're feeling philosophical, is that `DELETE` is idempotent.  After `DELETE /foo HTTP/1.1` there is no more /foo.  Whether or not it existed before, it certainly doesn't exist after the request, and therefore any delete that you have permission to do will *always* succeed... even if the object did not exist.

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam how can single image or single file will be delete in php Yii2 ?i did my best but can only delete the complete bucket or object. Any idea about this i need to delete the single image..?

Answer (score 3):

when you send the key dynamically, use local storage to store the key and send it dynamically to delete image

```
var s3 = AWS.S3(awsCredentials); 
s3.deleteObject({  
 Bucket: MY_BUCKET, 
 Key: 'yourFileKey' 
},function (err,data){})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the exact your key. For example: If it is in the root directory of the bucket,
 then `Key: "your key.extension"`. And, if it is in some other directory like `folder/subfolder/filename.extension.`, then you have to specify this.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
});

const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: `folder/subfolder/filename.fileExtension`
};

s3.deleteObject(params, (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
  res.status(200).send("File has been deleted successfully");
});
```